# How to plot 2D advection problem when using meshgrid to find value for velocity?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, nested, mesh

I am currently trying to solve a 2nd order 2D advection equation using the upwind scheme. At first the task is to plot a `quiver()` plot and then over lay it on top of a `contourf()`. When using the data for velocity u and v into the upwind scheme I am getting straight line outputs as seen below. However I am using an initial condition of `phi0 = cos(x)`. When checking the values for X,Y,u,v they all have different values at (i,j) locations. I see that my phi0 and phi are staying constant down each column but the output of the advection should be different at different times.  I followed my 1D 2nd order code which works perfectly, but cannot seem to get a advected moving graph. Any advice on my setup or if you can point out where I am going wrong with this plot would be a big help!

```
clear all
clc

%Problem 1
%Part B
%Creating a quiver plot for the 2D vector profile
L=2*pi;%Length Lx=Ly = 2pi
L0=0;
N=31; % Nx=Ny=31
%get a value of dx=dy to know distance between steps 
dx=L/N;
dy=L/N
 x=L0-dx*2:dx:L+dx*2;
 y=L0-dy*2:dy:L+dy*2;

[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);

u=cos(X).*sin(Y);
v=-sin(X).*cos(Y);

figure
hold on


%Part B & C using the courtf plot Phi=cos(x)
phi0=cos(X);
contourf(X,Y,phi0)
colormap autumn
colorbar
xlabel('Length from 0 to 2*pi with dx spacing')
ylabel('Length from 0 to 2*pi with dy spacing')
title('Quiver plot on the phi=cos(x) Contour Plot')
quiver(X,Y,u,v)
hold off

figure(2)
plot(x,phi0)
%%
%Writing a code to sovle 2D advection for  part D
t=0; %initial time
tmax=10; %Maximum time
dt=0.01; %time step

phi=phi0;
phip1=phi0;

%phi(:)=phi; %Initial Condition
nsteps = tmax/dt
%Add periodic boundary conditions for both x & y direction
for n=1 : nsteps
    phi(1,:) = phi(end-2,:);
    phi(2,:) = phi(end-3,:);
    phi(end,:) = phi(3,:);
    phi(end-1,:) = phi(4,:);
    %Y ghost cells
    phi(:,1) = phi(:,end-2);
    phi(:,1) = phi(:,end-3);
    phi(:,end) = phi(:,3);
    phi(:,end-1) = phi(:,4);

    for i=3:N+1
        for j=3:N+1

          if u > 0 & v>0
               phip1(i,j)= phi(i,j) - u(i)*dt/(2*dx) * (3*phi(i,j)-4*phi(i-1,j)+phi(i-2,j))- v(j)*dt/(2*dx) *(3*phi(i,j)-4*phi(i,j-1)+phi(i,j-2))
          elseif u <0 & v<0
               phip1(i,j)= phi(i,j) - u(i)*dt/(2*dx) * (-3*phi(i,j)+4*phi(i+1,j)-phi(i+2,j))- v(j)*dt/(2*dx) *(-3*phi(i,j)+4*phi(i,j+1)-phi(i,j+2))
          elseif u >0 & v <0
               phip1(i,j)= phi(i,j) - u(i)*dt/(2*dx) * (3*phi(i,j)-4*phi(i+1,j)+phi(i+2,j))- v(j)*dt/(2*dx) *(-3*phi(i,j)+4*phi(i,j-1)-phi(i,j-2))
          elseif u <0 & v >0
               phip1(i,j)= phi(i,j) - u(i)*dt/(2*dx) * (-3*phi(i,j)+4*phi(i-1,j)-phi(i-2,j))- v(j)*dt/(2*dx) *(3*phi(i,j)-4*phi(i,j+1)+phi(i,j+2))
          end
        end
    end
    t=t+dt;
    phi=phip1;


    plot(x,phi)
    %pause(0.5)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that you are plotting `phi` (which is 2D) against `x` (which is 1D).

I am not 100% sure on the right section you want to plot but something along the lines of this should work: `plot(x,phi0(1,:))`. What this does is to plot the first slice of `phi` in the `y` direction.

[image]

**EDIT**

To visualize `phi0` as function of both `X` and `Y`, you can use either `surf(X,Y,phi0)` or `mesh(X,Y,phi0)`.

Comment: would the mesh function be used here to plot the 2D of phi with respect to X and Y ?